# Class-first modelling issues

Tags: c#, model, umbraco, code-first, class-diagram

I'm using uSiteBuilder and I'm coming slightly unstuck with my model, and the class inheritence. As I understand it, uSiteBuilder only supports classes and not interfaces.

I have 3 document types:

```
Home (Title, RightColumnWidgets)
StandardContent (Title, RightColumnWidgets, HeaderTitle, HeaderIntro)
Listing (Title, HeaderTitle, HeaderInfo)
```

A few observations:

```
Home and StandardContent share Title and RightColumnWidgets
Home, StandardContent and Listing all share Title
StandardContent and Listing share Title, HeaderTitle and HeaderIntro
```

My attempts at the models were:

Model 1

```
       - Content (Title)
                  - PageHeader (HeaderTitle, HeaderIntro)      
                             - BaseTwoColumn (RightColumnWidgets)
                                        - StandardContent (CORRECT)
                                        - Home (INCORRECT AS Home should have no HeaderTitle or HeaderIntro properties)
                             - Listing (CORRECT)
```

Model 2

```
       - Content (Title)
                  - BaseTwoColumn (RightColumnWidgets)
                             - PageHeader (HeaderTitle, HeaderIntro)
                                        - StandardContent (CORRECT)
                             - Home (CORRECT)
                  - BaseOneColumn
                             - Listing (INCORRECT because HeaderTitle and HeaderIntro are missing, but BaseOneColumn cannot inherit from PageHeader otherwise properties from BaseTwoColumn will also be inherited)
```

Perhaps I haven't been able to solve this because the model is incorrectly designed? Perhaps this is a limitation of uSiteBuilder because I can't use interfaces?

Could anyone provide any pointers or alternative solutions? I'd be most grateful for any help.

Many thanks

dotdev

Comment: Can you actually show us the code? Code is universal.. while parsing your diagram at this hour of the morning is not.

Comment: Hi Simon, I havent put the code together for these particular models yet because I can't get the design straight in my mind. I could write the code, but it would just be one of the solutions I highlighted which are both wrong of course....